# How to UNION 10 tables in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have to perform many queries with union 10 tables, like below. I was struggling to find an efficient way to loop it from order0 to order9. Did anyone solve similar problem?

```
select col1, col2 from order0 union all
select col1, col2 from order1 union all
select col1, col2 from order2 union all
select col1, col2 from order3 union all
select col1, col2 from order4 union all
select col1, col2 from order5 union all
select col1, col2 from order6 union all
select col1, col2 from order7 union all
select col1, col2 from order8 union all
select col1, col2 from order9；
```

Comment: Your query should be fine.  What is your quetion?

Comment: what are you trying to achieve in this query? state it in your post

Comment: you seem to have a wrong database design. It smells like oder0 to order10 should really be one table

Comment: @e4c5, I don't know why our order information was recorded in our database like this.

Comment: @NewbeeDev, I was just tired of repeating to copy the same query to UNION them all. I'm trying to find to way to loop it.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, I was just trying to find a way to loop it. What if I need to union more than 100 order tables in the future?

Comment: what you really should be doing is merging tables.

Comment: In the future, you would fix the design

Answer (score 1):

You can create a view out of the UNION statement. That way you can refer to all orders in your queries by just using a view name (e.g. select * from orders;).

```
CREATE VIEW orders
AS 
select col1, col2 from order0 union all
select col1, col2 from order1 union all
select col1, col2 from order2 union all
select col1, col2 from order3 union all
select col1, col2 from order4 union all
select col1, col2 from order5 union all
select col1, col2 from order6 union all
select col1, col2 from order7 union all
select col1, col2 from order8 union all
select col1, col2 from order9；
```